# An issue with the negative sign in a table

Tags: tables

In the following table:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \small
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \textbf{Representation}     & \textbf{Configuration}             & \textbf{Correlation} & \textbf{p-value}                 & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Correlation\\ coefficient\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\# classes with\\ significant\\ correlation\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
            \multirow{6}{*}{Test suite} & \multirow{6}{*}{Without reduction} & Coverage and AC      & \multirow{6}{*}{\textless 0.001} & $−0.18$                                                      & 9                                                                                          \\ \cline{3-3} \cline{5-6} 
            &                                    & Coverage and ND      &                                  & $−$ 0.2                                                                       & 4                                                                                          \\ \cline{3-3} \cline{5-6} 
            &                                    & Coverage and NV      &                                  & −0.19                                                                      & 9                                                                                          \\ \cline{3-3} \cline{5-6} 
            &                                    & Coverage and IC      &                                  & 0.21                                                                       & 8                                                                                          \\ \cline{3-3} \cline{5-6} 
            &                                    & Coverage and PIC     &                                  & 0.2                                                                        & 4                                                                                          \\ \cline{3-3} \cline{5-6} 
            &                                    & Coverage and DBI     &                                  & 0.21                                                                       & 9                                                                                          \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

The negative numbers in the column `Correlation coefficient` are shown as positive. The negative sign `-` is not shown. I tried both `$-18$` and `$-$ 0.2` but none of them works.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: The sign in your MWE is not a `-` as in the body of your question, it is `−`. The latter is not by default recognised by LaTeX inside a table or outside of it, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334025/minus-isnt-shown-in-exponent-superscript/334027#334027

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some of the minus signs were Unicode en-dashes. Changing to a hyphen inside the dollar signs, cured the errors.

However, I suggest that you load either [siunitx](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) or [dcolumn](https://ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn) to align you column at the decimal sign. Also, [booktabs](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs), more space and no vertical rules will increase readability. See example 2.

**Example 1**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering\small
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
  \textbf{Representation} 
  & \textbf{Configuration}
  & \textbf{Correlation}
  & \textbf{p-value} 
  & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Correlation\\ coefficient\end{tabular}}
  & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\# classes with\\ significant\\ correlation\end{tabular}}\\
\hline
  \multirow{6}{*}{Test suite}
  & \multirow{6}{*}{Without reduction} 
  & Coverage and AC
  & \multirow{6}{*}{\textless 0.001}
  & $-0.18$
  & 9\\
\cline{3-3} \cline{5-6}
  &    & Coverage and ND  &    & $-$0.2  & 4 \\
\cline{3-3} \cline{5-6}
  &    & Coverage and NV  &    & $-$0.19 & 9 \\
\cline{3-3} \cline{5-6} 
  &    & Coverage and IC  &    &    0.21 & 8 \\
\cline{3-3} \cline{5-6}
  &    & Coverage and PIC &    &    0.2  & 4 \\
\cline{3-3} \cline{5-6} 
  &    & Coverage and DBI &    &    0.21 & 9 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Example 2**

With [booktabs](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs), [dcolumn](https://ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn) and no vertical space. `d-column` is in math mode, so no $ is needed. However, headings has to be enclosed in a `\multicolumn`. According to my textbooks, table heading should be bottom aligned, not vertically centred. You may also reduce the font size one grade.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow, dcolumn, booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[th!]
\centering\small
\begin{tabular}{@{}cclcD{.}{.}{-2}c@{}}
\toprule
  \textbf{Representation}
  &\textbf{Configuration}
  &\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}b{2.5cm}}{\bfseries Correlation}
  &\textbf{p-value}
  &\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}b{2.5cm}}{\bfseries Correlation coefficient}
  &\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}b{2.5cm}}{\bfseries \# classes with significant correlation}\\
\midrule
  \multirow{6}{*}{Test suite}
  &\multirow{6}{*}{Without reduction}
  & Coverage and AC
  &\multirow{6}{*}{\textless 0.001}
  & -0.18
  &9 \\ 
  &    & Coverage and ND  &    & -0.2   & 4 \\ 
  &    & Coverage and NV  &    & -0.19  & 9 \\ 
  &    & Coverage and IC  &    &  0.21  & 8 \\ 
  &    & Coverage and PIC &    &  0.2   & 4 \\ 
  &    & Coverage and DBI &    &  0.21  & 9 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```